# Why anaconda3 installation seems end up with python2 instead of python3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I don't get this:

On my Linux VM guest, I downloaded and installed Anaconda3 (https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh) with no error/warning.

I was assuming the new installation would be added to the PATH automatically, it seems not.

All I want to do are:
1. Using python3
2. Start Jupyter with python3 kernel

Can anyone shed me more light?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/) guide, it looks like `/path/to/anaconda/bin` is not added to `$PATH` directly. Once we run `conda init`, the `.bashrc` is changed to reflect the change in `$PATH`. The anaconda path gets added to `$PATH` once we run `conda activate` after running the `conda init` command.

If on the other hand, a virtual environment is created, and activated, the `$PATH` now points to `/path/to/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin`.

```sh
[root@user]#echo $PATH
# <PATH> 

<install conda>

[root@user]#echo $PATH
# unchanged <PATH>

[root@user]#conda init
[root@user]#echo $PATH
# unchanged <PATH>

[root@user]#conda activate
(base)[root@user]#echo $PATH 
# /path/to/anaconda/bin:<PATH>
```

```sh
[root@user]#conda create -n myenv ...
[root@user]#conda activate myenv
(myenv)[root@user]#echo $PATH
#path/to/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin:<PATH>
```

In order to install `python3` and `jupyter`, a good way would be:

1. [Create a conda virtual environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with `python3`
2. Install the libraries.

Although Anaconda [does not recommend](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/) manual addition to `$PATH` , you can manually [add it to path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760311/anaconda-i-have-to-type-export-path-anaconda3-bin-path-everytime-i-rerun) without creating a virtual environment to install the libraries.

Hope this helps